# Is there another way to install ncview using Anaconda?

Tags: python, conda, hdf5, netcdf4

I have tried installing it from conda-forge with the commands below:

```
conda install -c conda-forge ncview
```

I have also tried doing the same after creating my own environment variable and activating it.
I still get a "Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve." error.

Is there any other channel or way to import ncview in Anaconda

Comment: There is one other channel (see here: https://anaconda.org/search?q=ncview) that provides a `ncview` package. I think the question would benefit from giving more details about your requirements. E.g. what is it about the conda-forge package that doesn't work for you?

Comment: It doesn't appear to be available from that other channel, even though it is shown at https://anaconda.org/eumetsat/ncview. In fact `conda search ncview` returns a `PackagesNotFoundError`

Comment: have you tried `conda install -c eumetsat ncview` . thats on the official page of anaconda.

Comment: If all else fails, it does appear to be available via [Homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/ncview) so you could try installing via `brew install ncview`

Comment: @hamid.khb yes i have, still gave me the same error.

Comment: What OS are you using? Please also add the steps you took to create your own environment and activate it

Comment: Please provide the contents of the environment.